# How to: Click in WPF with a TargetType?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have so dinamically add some `MyLabel`s (custom WPF Controls) in `MyUserControl` (Custom UserControl).

I need to redirect the click on that labels to a function(say, `OnMyLabelClick`).

Can I associate a style or something with `TargetType='MyLabel'` in order to automatically redirect my click from each myLabel to that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyLabel}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                     Handler="MyLabel_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attached events for that.

Consider a simple example of attached events:

```
<StackPanel Label.MouseDown ="Label_MouseDown">
    <MyLabel>ABC</MyLabel>
    <MyLabel>DEF</MyLabel>
    <MyLabel>FGH</MyLabel>
</StackPanel>
```

Because of the way routed events work in WPF you can register the MouseDown event for all labels on a parent container (could be your user control).

If your MyLabel extends Label the above example will work

Comment: I tried `<Grid my:MyLabel.MouseDoubleClick="MyLabel_MouseDoubleClick">` this compiled, but any feedback from the event...

Comment: Hi. First, please note that in my example the used attached event is MouseDown, not a custom event, not the click event. I'm not sure how you implemented click on your label, you could have done it in a number of ways. Click is a routing event who's strategy is direct so it will not bubble through the tree of elements, see [routing strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx). Mouse Down is a routing event so it will bubble through the tree of elements, and that's why the above example works.

Comment: I don't need MouseDown, I need MouseDoubleClick... finally, I need a universal solution, not just one that works for MouseDown... I tested the Style solution and it works for any event...